# Number does not display in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to display the number "6155210417335" in excel but display another thing.

I want to display "6155210417335" without using any "'" or similiar.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply making the column wider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widen the column and change the value format from "General" to "Number".

Comment: Is it possible to make it automatically to turn it into a number in the cell when you paste the data?

Comment: You could try pre-formatting the cells so that they are in Number format. Then by right-clicking on the desired cells you can use Paste-Special >> Values.